# Elegant parsing with R a huge text table

Tags: python, r, bash

i have a huge table with 3 columns tab-separated consisting of a deep analysis on burgers.
Here's a fraction of the table (Sorry for the delimiters).

```
NAME@FEATURE@DESCRIPTION
Kburger@supplier@Jackobs12
Kburger@type@Minkins Carnivorous
Kburger@deposit@http://minkins.sord/deposit/Kburger
Kburger@opinions@shitty::very gummy|shitty::grey
Kburger@code@HB3T2323|Tried just once; IT IS: disgusting…
Aburger@supplier@Mark11
Aburger@type@Minkins Carnivorous
Aburger@deposit@http://minkins.sord/deposit/Aburger
Aburger@opinions@shitty::very gummy
Cburger@supplier@David22
Cburger@type@Minkins Carnivorous
Cburger@deposit@http://minkins.sord/deposit/Cburger
Cburger@opinions@shitty::very gummy|slightly hard::never again
Dburger@supplier@Jason99
Dburger@type@Minkins Carnivorous
Dburger@deposit@http://minkins.sord/deposit/Dburger
Dburger@opinions@shitty::very gummy
Eburger@supplier@CarlX
Eburger@type@Minkins Vegetarian
Eburger@deposit@http://minkins.sord/deposit/Eburger
Eburger@opinions@shitty::very gummy|shitty::abnormal
Fburger@supplier@Dino12
Fburger@type@Minkins Vegetarian
Fburger@deposit@http://minkins.sord/deposit/Fburger
Fburger@opinions@shitty::very gummy
Fburger@code@HB3T5554|Reminds me about vomit (N3VER); MEMORIES: No other comments...
```

As you see, for some of the burger names, we have 5 features instead of 4, displaying the "code" feature (always starting with HB) that in many cases is missing. What i want is to parse this table with R and getting a 3 column tab-separated summary table with in one line code, name and opinions, like this :

```
CODE    NAME    DESCRIPTION
HB3T2323    Kburger shitty::very gummy|shitty::grey
HB3T5554    Fburger shitty::very gummy
```

This is my rough solution in bash im really ashamed of:

```
cat table.txt  | tr '@' '\t' | grep "HB" | cut -d '|' -f1,3 | cut -f1,3 | while read i; do echo $(echo $i | awk '{print $2}') && grep $(echo $i | awk '{print $1}') table.txt | grep "opinions" ; done  | tr '@' '\t' | paste - - | cut -f1,2,4 > new_table.txt
```

If you can also provide a solution in bash or python will be also appreciated, but honestly i prefer R.

Comment: `gsub("^HB\\S*\\|", "", x$DESCRIPTION)`?

Comment: `cat table.txt | sed -e 's/\bHB[^|]*|//g'`

Comment: they both dont work :(

Comment: That *barely* helps. **How** does it fail? It sounds like your data is not what you are depicting it as. For instance, if instead of starting a column `HB...` is somewhere other than the very beginning, it will not match the pattern. I tried to make it very specific based on your example so as to not change other things elsewhere. Perhaps you could edit your question and include the output from `dput(x)` where `x` is enough rows to include some with, some without the problem? (There is no need for 26 rows, 3-5 will suffice to get the point across.)

Comment: Yes please `dput` data because as given your table does not have consistent delimiters

Comment: sorry i dont know what should i do, can you be more clear?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a potential R solution using the dplyr and tidyr packages.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- read.delim(file = "PATH/TO/TAB/DELIMITED/FILE/HERE.txt")

df <- df %>%
      spread(key = "FEATURE", value = "DESCRIPTION") %>%
      separate(col = "code", into = c("code", "code_desc"), sep = "\\|", extra = "merge", fill = "right") %>%
      filter(!is.na(code)) %>%
      select("CODE" = code, NAME, "DESCRIPTION" = opinions)

write.table(df, "PATH/TO/TAB/DELIMITED/OUTPUT/FILE/HERE.txt", sep = "\t", na = "", row.names = FALSE)
```